# Updating a value in an observable without resolving prior operators

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

Here is what I am trying to do: I have a list of users coming from an async data source. The source returns an `Observable<User[]>`. The list is then displayed in the template via Angular's `async` pipe like this.

```
<ng-template #loading>Loading...</ng-template>
<ul *ngIf="users$ | async; let users; else loading">
  <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

The list of users is searchable. Using reactive forms, I have bound the search field's change event like this (with `this.resolve` performing the async task, having the signature `(text: string) => Observable<User[]>`):

```
search = new FormControl('');
users$ = this.search.valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(this.search.value))
  .pipe(debounceTime(250))
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .pipe(switchMap(this.resolve));
```

This works perfectly fine. The search input is debounced and a new async request to resolve the users is fired when the search input changes.

Now I have a problem. Users may change on the client side and need to be updated in the list **without** performing the async task again. My attempt to use another pipe operation in the update function results in `this.resolve` being executed again.

```
update(user: User): void {
  this.users$ = this.users$
    .pipe(map(users => {
      // replace user in users
      return users;
    }));
}
```

However, I **do not** want to resolve the users again. I just want to **locally** update the async user list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Subject` and merge it into the `users$` chain after `switchMap`.

```
otherUsers$ = new Subject();

users$ = this.search.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    startWith(this.search.value),
    debounceTime(250)),
    distinctUntilChanged()),
    switchMap(this.resolve),
    merge(otherUsers$),
  );
```

Then you can call `next()` and avoid going through the whole chain:

```
otherUsers$.next([{}, {}, {}, ...]);
```

Comment: How do I access the values of `users$` when calling `next()` on `otherUsers$`? I can see how this works to update all users, but what if I want to update a single user in the values of `users$`?

Comment: Then use `combineLatest` instead of `merge` and use eg. `BehaviorSubject` instead of `Subject`.

Comment: Can you help me out with a little example here? I am trying to get my head around observables... I have prepared an example implementation at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-ohjvxv. Not sure if this is the canonical way to use Observables for filtering and paging anyways. But how can I implement the update function that changes one element of the current page without re-resolving the page itself?

Comment: You can do it like this for example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-caszhe?file=src/app/app.component.ts
But it really only depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is not exactly what I was looking for, as this will re-apply the update every time the page is changed. It should only be applied once. However, this does point me in the right direction and I will continue from there!

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to martin's `merge()` suggestion, I would also "share" the users result to prevent the `resolve` from firing again.

RXJS will run through all the pipes every time a subscription is added. Think of them as transformers where the "datastore" is the initial `Subject` (`this.search.valueChanges`). So every time you subscribe, RXJS is going to run through your pipes to get the transformed value.

So you want to look at RXJS [`share()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/share.html) or [`shareReplay(1)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html). What these will do is internally create a `new Subject()` (in the case of `share()`) or a `new ReplaySubject(1)` (in the case of `shareReplay(1)`) to hold your transformed value in a new "datastore", if you will.

```js
search = new FormControl('');
otherUsers$ = new Subject();
users$ = merge(
  otherUsers$,
  this.search.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(this.search.value)),
    debounceTime(250)),
    distinctUntilChanged()),
    switchMap(this.resolve))
  )
).pipe(share());
```

`Subject` vs `ReplaySubject` depends on whether you want to hold a value even when there is no subscription. (This is my interpretation based on my own usage.) I found `shareReplay(1)` useful in cases where I have subscriptions like `obs.pipe(first()).subscribe(...)`. However one of your subscriptions is the `AsyncPipe` in the DOM, so you're probably fine with `share()`, but try it out yourself.